# Setting 86duino One COM1 port to other port

Tags: serial-port, dos

I am using 86duino ONE board. Currently, COM1 is located at PORT 1 (GP12 & GP13 if i am not mistaken). How do i move this COM1 to PORT 8 (any GPIO)?

I need to do this on FDOS.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it's not a question about programming.

Comment: unless the COM is not just SW then you can not move it to any pin unless you physically change its location (by some jumper or whatever). I am not familiar with 86duino but it suggest it uses x86 CPU instead of MCU. x86 architecture does not have any serial ports on chip so interconnnecting through jumper is a possibility if designers implement it on the board. In case it uses standard MCU like atmell, PIC or whatever they have serial ports on chip and you have only few possibilities to change it locations depending on their internal connections see the pinouts in datasheet of the chip used

Comment: This is a programming question since it needs a coding to answer my question. This is not just about change any jumper.. This is a microprocessor programming level.